# PHP move_uploaded_file permission denied (permission set to 755)

Tags: php, file-permissions

I'm trying to upload a user's photo using a simple HTML input form, but I'm getting the following error. I've set the permissions of my upload folder to 755. I tried 777 and that works, but I've read that setting it to 777 is not advised and that I should be able to use 755?

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/2014_08_21_11_03_14k.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/yadayada/register.php on line 136
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php8KQwyh' to 'uploads/2014_08_21_11_03_14k.jpg' in /home/yadayada/register.php on line 136
```

This is my php code:

```
$userPhotoUrl = 'uploads/'.date('Y_m_d_H_i_s').$_FILES['photo']['name'];

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $userPhotoUrl)) {
        // show error message
        return;
    }
} else {
    // show error message
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand what is 755.

For folder, **755** means `drwxr-xr-x`, which means:

- Owner has Read, Write & Execute permission
- Group & Public have Read and Execute permission only

As the user running PHP is probably not the owner of the folder, it does not have write permission to the folder. Either:

- You `chown` the folder to PHP's user; or
- You make it `777`: everybody has Read, Write & Execute permission

Of course, the latter choice has a security issue, as if somebody uploads an executable shell script to your folder, he can execute the script. Therefore, you should stick with the first choice.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I had placed the .htaccess file in the wrong folder. Works now :)

Comment: FYI, `chown` can be run in server's shell, via SSH probably.

Comment: Doesn't `r-x` means Read and Execute? Why did you say it's "Read permission only"?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably chown the upload folder (move) to the same user as PHP runs under. Try this

```
chown -R nobody uploaddir
chmod -R 755 uploaddir
```

Answer (score 0):

Have alook on this [Permission](https://www.drupal.org/node/39887)

if you set 755, your webserver will be the owner of the folder.

Comment: huh? not true. The folder owner is not necessarily the user of web server's user.